# How do I log out the Acumatica Web Api user?

Tags: acumatica

I'm running into a problem on our test environment, which has a limit of two users, where it constantly boots me out because the Web API user logs in over and over as needed to sync data. So I thought I'd ask to see if there is a way to get the Web API to log out when it finishes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of acumatica?

Acumatica 4.x and below did not have a method to log off.  What I've done is create a singleton class for my Acumatica methods and add a common "Validate" method so it re-uses an existing connection.

Something like the following:

```
    private void Validate(bool forceLogin = false, int trycount = 0)
    {
        if (trycount == 2)
        {
            //throw new AcumaticaException("Could not login to Acumatica Instance");
        }
        if (_container == null || forceLogin)
        {
            _container = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
            if (forceLogin != true)
            {
                forceLogin = true;
            }
        }
        _guruscreen = new Screen
        {
            CookieContainer = _container,
            AllowAutoRedirect = true,
            EnableDecompression = true,
            Timeout = 1000000,
            Url = AcumaticaUrl
        };

        if (forceLogin)
        {
            _guruscreen.Login("webservice", "WebServicePwd");
        }

        try
        {
            _guruscreen.UntypedClear("CW900000");
        }
        catch
        {
            // if session expired, login again and resend request
            Validate(true, trycount++);
        }
    }
```

Then in each of my methods before calling the Export/Submit I call Validate() to see if an existing connection exists, see if it's still active and if not try to reconnect.

If you are in Acumatica 5.x, there is a logout method.

A sample of that is below

```
private const string Url = "http://localhost/WebServices_5-0/Soap/DemoService.asmx";
private const string UntypedUrl = "http://localhost/WebServices_5-0/Soap/.asmx";
private const string Login = "xxxxx";
private const string Password = "XXX";

public void ExportStockItems()
{
    Screen context = new Screen();
    context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
    context.Url = Url;
    context.Login(Login, Password);

    IN202500Content stockItemsSchema = context.IN202500GetSchema();
    var commands = new Command[]
    {
    stockItemsSchema.StockItemSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryInventoryID,
    stockItemsSchema.StockItemSummary.InventoryID,
    stockItemsSchema.StockItemSummary.Description,
    stockItemsSchema.GeneralSettingsItemDefaults.ItemClass,
    stockItemsSchema.GeneralSettingsUnitOfMeasureBaseUnit.BaseUnit,
    stockItemsSchema.PackagingDimensions.Volume,
    stockItemsSchema.PackagingDimensions.Weight
    };
    var filters = new Filter[]
    {
    new Filter
    {
        Field = new Field 
        {
        ObjectName = stockItemsSchema.StockItemSummary.InventoryID.ObjectName,
        FieldName = "LastModifiedDateTime" 
        },
        Condition = FilterCondition.Less,
        Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(),
        Operator = FilterOperator.And
    },
    new Filter
    {
        Field = new Field 
        {
        ObjectName = stockItemsSchema.StockItemSummary.ItemStatus.ObjectName,
        FieldName = stockItemsSchema.StockItemSummary.ItemStatus.FieldName 
        },
        Condition = FilterCondition.Equals,
        Value = "Active",
    }
    };
    var items = context.IN202500Export(commands, filters, 0, false, false);

    UntypedDemoServiceRef.Screen untypedContext = new UntypedDemoServiceRef.Screen();
    context.Url = UntypedUrl;
    untypedContext.CookieContainer = context.CookieContainer;
    untypedContext.Logout();
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks! wondering if the line "context.Url = UntypedUrl;" is a logic bug? Should it be "untypedContext.Url = UntypedUrl;"

Comment: That's a good question.   The sample above was sent to me by Acumatica when I asked this exact same question.   I don't have any clients on 5.1 who use WebAPI so I've never actually had to use it