# Acumatica Web API and Site User Booted with message - You have been logged out due to exceeding the number of users in the system

Tags: acumatica

I'm running into an issue with being booted from the Acumatica Website (V5.2 trial version) whenever the Web API code runs to sync data displaying the message "You have been logged out due to exceeding the number of users in the system" even though I have implemented web API logout code.

I would like to not be booted from Acumatica and have previously asked the question [How do I log out the Acumatica Web Api user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441694/how-do-i-log-out-the-acumatica-web-api-user/31442177#31442177). 
Which is where I got the code to log out. But it definitely is not working correctly on my trial version..

So I'm thinking there is something wrong with my code and if so could use some help in figuring it out.

Replication Steps: Before running my example code below, log into a trial version of Acumatica. After running, you will be booted from Acumatica saying you have exceeded the two user limit.

The below example code just logs in, searches for a sales person by id, and then logs out. It does this twice.

Example Code:

```
class Program
{
    static AcumaticaApiWS.Screen context = null;
    static string contextUrl = "http://localhost/Soap/WEBAPI.asmx";
    static string screenUrl = "http://localhost/Soap/.asmx";
    static string userName = "USERNAME";
    static string passWord = "PASSWORD";

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        LogIn();
        DoWork("Test1");
        LogOut();

        LogIn();
        DoWork("Test2");
        LogOut();
    }

    static void LogIn()
    {
        Program.context = new AcumaticaApiWS.Screen();
        Program.context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        Program.context.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        Program.context.EnableDecompression = true;
        Program.context.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
        Program.context.Url = Program.contextUrl;
        AcumaticaApiWS.LoginResult result = context.Login( Program.userName, Program.passWord );
        Program.context.SetLocaleName( System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name );
    }

    static void LogOut()
    {
        AcumaticaScreenWS.Screen screen = new AcumaticaScreenWS.Screen();
        Program.context.Url = Program.screenUrl;
        screen.Url = Program.screenUrl;
        screen.CookieContainer = Program.context.CookieContainer;
        screen.Logout();
        Program.context = null;
    }

    static void DoWork( string salesPersonId )
    {
        String[][] AR205000data = null;

        AcumaticaApiWS.AR205000Content AR205000 = Program.context.AR205000GetSchema();
        Program.context.AR205000Clear();

        AR205000data = Program.context.AR205000Export
        (
            new AcumaticaApiWS.Command[]
            {
                AR205000.SalespersonInfo.ServiceCommands.EverySalespersonID,
                AR205000.SalespersonInfo.SalespersonID,
                AR205000.SalespersonInfo.Name
            },
            new AcumaticaApiWS.Filter[]
            {
                new AcumaticaApiWS.Filter
                {
                    Field = new AcumaticaApiWS.Field() {
                            FieldName = AR205000.SalespersonInfo.SalespersonID.FieldName,
                            ObjectName = AR205000.SalespersonInfo.SalespersonID.ObjectName
                    },
                    Condition = AcumaticaApiWS.FilterCondition.Equals,
                    Value = salesPersonId
                }
            },
            0, false, false
        );

        if( AR205000data.Length > 0 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( AR205000data[0][0] + " " + AR205000data[0][1] );
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "'" + salesPersonId + "' not found." );
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We are investigating - we had reports of a similar issue with licensed versions and your sample is the best yet to help us replicate the problem. Thanks.

Comment: We found the bug - will be fixed in the next 5.2/4.2 updates. If you need a hotfix urgently please drop me an e-mail.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!